# How to handle notification actions with flutter_local_notification package?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I have added 2 buttons to my notification in the code below
But I don't know how to find out which button is pressed and do something based on that

```
  Future<void> zonedScheduleAlarmClockNotification({
    required Duration duration,
    required String title,
    required String message,
    required String type,
  }) async {
    print(duration);
    final random = Random();
    int id = random.nextInt(999999999);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      message,
      tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(duration),
      
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'alarm_clock_channel',
          'Alarm Clock Channel',
          channelDescription: 'Alarm Clock Notification',
          subText: type,
          //silent: true,
          color: Colors.amber,
          colorized: true,
          ticker: title,
          playSound: true,
          priority: Priority.high,
          importance: Importance.high,
          
          actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
            const AndroidNotificationAction(
              'id_2',
              'Completed',
              titleColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
              icon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('secondary_icon'),
            ),
             const AndroidNotificationAction(
              's',
              'Action 3',
              icon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('secondary_icon'),
              showsUserInterface: true,
              // By default, Android plugin will dismiss the notification when the
              // user tapped on a action (this mimics the behavior on iOS).
              cancelNotification: false,
            ), 
          ],
        ),
      ),
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.alarmClock,
      payload: title,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }
```

I wanted the user to perform tasks within the app on each of the buttons he pressed
But I can't figure out how to find out which button the user clicked and when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you could see in the [document](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#notification-actions), it needs some configuration for iOS, but then, if you have done that, or you are on android, it is said that you should declare a top level function to receive the notification in the app and act on it. There you could check the `actionId` of `notificationResponse` and act accordingly.

For instance, in your project here you could write something like:

```dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  if (notificationResponse.actionId == 'id_2') {
    // do something
  } else if (notificationResponse.actionId == 's') {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: It was great that this method worked.
thanks a lot❤️